# Difference between different session types in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, server

What is the difference between **security sessions**, **reliable sessions** and **TCP sessions** in `WCF`? They all do the same in my opinion.

Comment: What is there to add if you have decided already?

Comment: Changed title, highlighted keywords